# arrays inside of the list

Tags: java, arrays, list

I tried to find what's wrong with this simple code, I tried to search on this website for sample but could't find it. 
I want to create list of arrays. So when I call myList.get(0) it will output first array1. And if myList.get(0)[0] the very first value.
Thank you
My code:

```
List<int[]> myList = new ArrayList<int[]>();
    int[] array1 =  {15, 20, 40};
    int[] array2 =  {30, 7, 18};

    myList.add(array1);
    myList.add(array2);
    System.out.println(myList);
```

Gives this kind of output. [[I@129f3b5, [I@13f3045]

Comment: its perfectly correct , what is that you expect and not happening

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example `myList.get(0)` will return an array of ints, because that's what your list contains.

So if you want to print all the elements of the array you should do something like

```
for (int[] array : myList) {
    for (Integer i : array) {
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You have to do something like this, import `java.util.Arrays` and use this static method [Arrays#toString(int[])](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString%28int%5B%5D%29)

```
for(int[] a : myList) {
   System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This will first print out each value on a new line, now you should probably edit the output by yourself. And the second loop will print out each table using Arrays.toString()

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<int[]> myList = new ArrayList<int[]>();
    int[] array1 = { 15, 20, 40 };
    int[] array2 = { 30, 7, 18 };

    myList.add(array1);
    myList.add(array2);
    for (int[] tables : myList)
        for (int i : tables)
            System.out.println(i);
    //This is also possible
    for (int[] tables : myList)
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(tables));

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should print it like that:

```
for(int i = 0; i < myList.size(); i++) {
    int[] numbers = myList.get(i);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(numbers));
}
```

Array is  *Object*, and as you know, each object has [`toString`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29) method. The default `toString` displays the class name representation, then adds `@` and then the hashcode.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, Java arrays don't have a good `toString()` method that would return a well-formatted view of the elements it contains. And `System.out.println(Object)` actually calls this bad `toString()` method, which simply returns the type of the array (`[[I`) followed by its hash code.

To get a meaningful representation of an array, use `java.util.Arrays.toString()`:

```
for (int[] array : myList) {
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Arrays.toString()`  to print the array. ;

```
System.out.printlin(myList.get(0)) // first Array from the list
System.out.printlin(myList.get(1)) // second Array from the list
```

Use below code to print entire list.

```
   for(int[] array : myList) {
          System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

The code is correct. However, you have to remember that you can't simple print an array, but have to do something like 
    `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(myList));`

Answer (score 0):

The

> I@129f3b5
>
> I@13f3045

are the default `toString()` implementations for arrays.

So the code is completely correct, the arrays are stored in the list. Just the `toString()` is not of much use for arrays.

Simply - you should not rely on array `toString()`.